# Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created custom shipping module and gets following error:

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in **/home/devjoand/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping.php** on line **421**

I removed all files including .xml for this shipping module and it still gives me the same error. It doesn't send me to shipping method and stops execution from savebilling controller with above error. I have cleared cache/session and recompile but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

NOTE: It works fine in my local machine but not working on production server.

Comment: I don't know how to help you because you don't give code. Anyway you can read: [reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983).

Comment: The variable you think is an object and on which you try to call <code>setStore()</code> is not an object. So you are trying to instantiate an object like, <code>$obj = new Obj()</code> and the try to call <code>$obj->setStore()</code>, but your <code>$obj</code> has faild to get instantiated. Wrap it in a <code>try-catch</code> block and dump the exception, to see if theres an error.

Comment: I am getting error after filling Billing Information and then click "Continue". Basically i have removed my custom shipping module and clear cache so i think the default Magento shipping method should work but instead it gives me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described partially in the comments, the error comes from this code:

```
    $obj = Mage::getModel($className);
    if ($storeId) {
        $obj->setStore($storeId);
    }
```

In the code above `$obj` is set to `null`.
You stated that your removed a shipping carrier.
I think the problem appears because you didn't deactivate first the carrier.
So in the config table the carrier appears to be enabled but there is no model associated to it so the code above fails.

In order to fix this, look in the table `core_config_data` for a record with this path column: `carriers/CARRIER_CODE_HERE/active`, where `CARRIER_CODE_HERE` is the code of the shipping method you just removed.

When you find the line, remove it.  Actually remove everything that has a path like `carriers/CARRIER_CODE_HERE/%`.
be sure to backup your database first in case I'm wrong.